# Is it possible to use google maps api autocomplete.getPlace() without putting it in a place_changed listener?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I also tried to trigger the event

```
google.maps.event.trigger(autocomplete, 'place_changed');
```

but autocomplete.getPlace() is still return undefined until I change the city manually.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From google docs: **getPlace()**: *Returns the details of the Place selected by user if the details were successfully retrieved. Otherwise returns a stub Place object, with the name property set to the current value of the input field.*

Using for example the following code:

```
    var autocompleteSearch = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchField, searchOptions);

    setInterval(function() {
        var place = autocompleteSearch.getPlace();
        console.log('place: ');
        console.log(place);
    }, 5000);
```

you will get 'undefined' in console if you wrote for example "qwertyasdfgh". Until you press Enter: after that the result will be:

```
place:  
Object {name: "qwertyasdfgh"}
```

So, it's not much useful. No `address_components`, `geometry`...

Comment: Thank you for the answer... I'm slightly disappointed, cause i have to implement another autocomplete then...